# Is there any way to run python script from Azure File Shares using Batch Service activity in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I know how to run python script using Batch Service in Azure Data Factory if script is located in Blob Storage Container.

But I need to put script in Azure File Shares and execute it using Batch Service custom activity

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is not possible to run python script from Azure File share using Batch Service Activity in ADF as Azure Batch connector is linked to a blob storage and hence won't be able to establish a connection to File storage from Azure Batch connector.

[image]

I would recommend you to log a feature request here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c

All the feedback shared in this forum are actively monitored and reviewed by ADF product team.